# Layout de Java Web para Desktop

Tags: java, framework

Estou analisando uma forma de desenhar tela mais agradáveis e próximas da web.

Procurei na internet e sei que com o JavaFX eu consigo desenhar telas ricas e bonitas, gostaria de saber se existe mais algum framework ou tecnologia que posso usar para desenhar telas assim.

Comment: cara vai de javaFX mesmo por que alem de ser uma tendência ele é o padrão oracle

Comment: Recomendo mesmo o `JavaFx`, quanto ao desenhar telas mais bonitas podias mesmo é mudar as propriedades de apresentação dos componentes `swing` o que já ajudaria muito.

Comment: amplo demais porque?